# Getting empty array from get

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i'm going to localhost:3000/api/categories i'm getting an empty array, but when i log my products there is alot of data inside the object. Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
let products = getData()

function getData() {
return fetch('some url',
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
).then(res => res.json())
};

app.get(('/api/categories'), (req, res) => {
    products.then(console.log);
    res.send(products);
    products.then(console.log);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`products` is a *promise*. You can't send it to the client via `res.send`.

Instead, do what you're doing when you log it: use `then`:

```
app.get(('/api/categories'), (req, res) => {
    products
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(error => {
        // Send an error
    });
});
```

---

Note that your code gets the products **once**, at startup, and then responds to the request with that static set of products.

If you want to get the products in response to the request from the client, remove the

```
let products = getData();
```

and put it in the `get` handler:

```
app.get(('/api/categories'), (req, res) => {
    this.getData()
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(error => {
        // Send an error
    });
});
```

That repeats the request each time the client calls your server.

Of course, you might consider a middle ground, keeping and reusing the data for X seconds...